# NameError: name 'model' is not defined Keras with f1_score

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, scikit-learn, f1score

I'm having a problem with my Keras model, in the .compile() I use accuracy, loss, precision, recall and AUC, but also I need f1_score, due to Keras doesn´t include f1_score, I tried to calculate by myself but I get this error `NameError: name 'model' is not defined`, here's my code:

```
def residual_network_1d(input_shape):
    n_feature_maps = 64
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(input_shape)

    # BLOCK 1
    conv_x = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=n_feature_maps, kernel_size=8, padding='same')(input_layer)
    ...
    # FINAL
    gap_layer = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(output_block_3)
    output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(27, activation='softmax')(gap_layer)
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

    return model
```

`residual_network_1d_model=residual_network_1d(input_shape = (5000,1))`

```
def f1_score(y_test,y_pred):
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
    y_test = np.argmax(folds[0][1],axis=0)
    y_pred1 = model.predict(x=pc.generate_validation_data(ecg_filenames,y,folds[0][1])[0])
    y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred1, axis=1)
    my_f1_score=f1_score(y_test, y_pred , average="macro")
return my_f1_score
```

```
   residual_network_1d_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(
        name='accuracy', dtype=None, threshold=0.5),tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='Recall'),tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='Precision'),f1_score,
                    tf.keras.metrics.AUC(
        num_thresholds=200,
        curve="ROC",
        summation_method="interpolation",
        name="AUC",
        dtype=None,
        thresholds=None,
        multi_label=True,
        label_weights=None,
    )])
```

Why say `model is not defined` if I load my model previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `f1_score` function you are calling `model.predict`, but the function only takes the variables `y_test` and `y_pred` as input. Therefore the `model` variable you are referring to is not defined within the scope of this function.

Comment: So, what can I do, or how can I solve that? Or how can I calculate f1_score with my model?

Comment: I am not sure why you are using `model.predict` within your `f1_score` function since the predicted y values are already provided to the function as an argument, and would therefore assume that you can simply remove that method call. Another option would be to use the [`F1Score` implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score) of the `tensorflow-addons` package.

Comment: The code is an adaptation from other and in the original the author uses `model.predict`, to generate y_pred, and where are predicted y values generated?

Comment: They are predicted behind the scenes in `model.fit`, where the labels and predicted values are passed to the different metrics supplied in `model.compile` to calculate those metrics.

Comment: I use `tensorflow.addons` and apparently works fine, thanks.

Comment: Which average should I use? none, micro or macro?

Answer (score 0):

Add below to the top and it should work:

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression().fit(x_train,y_train)
print(model)

#This is a Linear Reg example you can change according to your need also don't forget to change X_Train and y_train acc to your variables.

Good luck

Comment: please use code formatting